# if(check) command in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I recently saw this function in a program I am studying. The global, check is set to equal one:

```
s=snew(s_old, beta,alpha,dt)
global check
s=s_old+dt*alpha/(1+dt*alpha*beta);
if(check)
   chsnew=(s-s_old)/dt-(s-(alpha-(1-s)-beta*s);
end
```

I don't understand the if(check) sequence. Can someone explain?

Comment: afaik `if` will check if the expression (here `check`) is not equal to zero. If that is the case, the statement in the `if` body is executed. Otherwise it is ignored. So `if(1)` will perform `chsnew=...` whereas `if(0)` will ignore that line.

Comment: Seems like any other [`if` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)#If.E2.80.93then.28.E2.80.93else.29) really.

Comment: Thank you Willem. Explained so simply, it now seems obvious! I should have seen the meaning right away.

Answer (score 0):

The global variable "check" can be set to 1 or 0 in order to enter or not in the "if" statement.

The same can be done for example when you are debugging code and want to execute some instructions in this context:

```
debug=1;
if (debug)
   <code to execute when debugging>
end
```